# Separate connection from PDO

Tags: php, pdo, database-connection

I am new to PDO. I try to understand.

What is the best way to separate the connection from the rest with PDO?

For instance. I have this code that works well:

```
<?php  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "podcast";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully <br>";

    $sql = "SELECT podcast, text 
            FROM bookmarks 
            WHERE data = :data";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $data = 1;
    $statement->bindValue(':data', $data);
    $statement->execute();
    echo $statement->rowCount() . " records SELECTED successfully <br>";

    $rows = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($rows as $row){
        echo $row['podcast'] . '<br>';
        echo $row['text'] . '<br>';
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

It could be useful to have the connection in a separate file. I tried that and it works well but I am not sure if it is the best way to do it. Is it ok to have the try-catch only with the connection?

index.php:

```
include("includes/connetion.php")
$sql = "SELECT podcast, text 
        FROM bookmarks 
        WHERE data = :data";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$data = 1;
$statement->bindValue(':data', $data);
$statement->execute();
echo $statement->rowCount() . " records SELECTED successfully <br>";

$rows = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo $row['podcast'] . '<br>';
    echo $row['text'] . '<br>';
}

$conn = null;
```

connection.php:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "podcast";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // $conn = new PDO("sqlite:/Applications/MAMP/db/sqlite/podcast", $username, $password); //Lite

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully <br>"; 
    }

catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well... It's not that bad, but you won't catch any errors returned by a botched query - only specific connection-errors. If there is an error in a query, you will either have to create a separate error-functionality, or add try/catch-blocks to each query.

Comment: If you cannot connect to the database, then what? What's the rest of your app going to do? Why do you let it continue running needlessly just to produce more errors down the line? **Why are you catching the exception?**

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie what's wrong with not catching errors?

Comment: @deceze: I do not know. That is why I ask. I just show some things that I tried

Comment: Uhm... okay? If you're not catching errors, how the hell are you gonna debug a problem? You don't have to echo the errors, but logging them might be prudent. Note: you don't always have access to the server's error-logs (especially on shared hosting).

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie imagine there is a problem with include due to permission error. if you don't have access to the server's error-logs, how the hell are you gonna debug this problem?

Comment: Eh, what? "A problem with include"? Why would there be a problem with the include? I'm talking about logging / debugging actual code - an include is basically not what I am talking about here...

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie but imagine there is. Just imagine. So, there is a problem with include due to permission error. if you don't have access to the server's error-logs, how the hell are you gonna debug this problem?

Comment: You can't. Simple as that. Not without getting the error-logs from the server, which will usually involve getting a hold of the ISP-support, which might take a day or two, then looking through the logs, try a fix, and if that doesn't work, go to start and try again. But the chance of having permission issues on (sane) includes are next to nill. But of course, not everything is sanely coded, of course...

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie, segon If you do not catch the exception, it'll cause a fatal error which will automatically be logged. If you don't have access to the error logs, 1) your setup is cr\*p, 2) you can add `ini_set('display_errors', true)` to your file to see any and all errors, including the full exception with stack trace, displayed on the page. You don't need to roll your own error reporting, use the one PHP already gives you.

Comment: Jeezus... I know that. And "your setup is crap" means nothing - thousands of users have shared hosting without access to server-side logs. And it's not always about showing the errors, more often than not its about logging errors so they're NOT DISPLAYED TO THE USERS - especially since PHP often spews out information that should NEVER be accessible to a user to begin with...

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie So how is `"Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage()` any better? It spews error messages regular users shouldn't see. That leaves you with: if you don't have access to the logs, you should not be able to see any sort of error message ever, which makes it impossible to debug your stuff. Ergo: cr\*p server setup.

Comment: *HEADDESK* That's why you don't SPEW THAT OUT TO THE USER, you log it to a file you DO have access to. How is this hard to understand?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie so just tell PHP to log errors to a file you DO have access to. ALL errors, not just one you are aware of

Answer (score 0):

> I tried that and it works well but I am not sure if it is the best way to do it.

As long as your code is a usual spaghetti as shown above, it's all right with include.

> Is it ok to have the try-catch only with the connection?

quite contrary, [there shouldn't be a try catch](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) with the connection as well:

"Catch an exception only if you have a handling scenario other than just reporting it. Otherwise just let it bubble up to a site-wide handler (note that you don't have to write one, there is a basic built-in handler in PHP, which is quite good)."

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to catch possible exception you have to do it everywhere you communicate with database. So you have to wrap try-catch also around code which ask database for some data.

Another step is to separate concepts of getting data from database representing them (sending them to output as you do it). You can check some MVC concept - how to do it.

Comment: Why one would wrap try-catch around code which ask database for some data?

Comment: What if you have a mistake in your SQL when requesting data from DB? You want catch possible mistake a manipulate with that exception. If you are not catching that exception your application should possibly end with fatal error. Thats why.